# Filtering parent or child database entity - optimization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing some optimizations and I need some technical help regarding optimization.

Consider the following query :

```
SELECT *
  FROM Employees E
  JOIN Data D ON E.idDataType = D.idDataType
WHERE E.idDataType = 1
```

Does it matter (from optimization point of view) if I filter the parent table or the child table? Which one would be faster?

```
E.idDataType  = 1 VS D.idDataType = 1
```

**Employees**:

```
|idEmployee|Name|Data1|idDataType|AttributeValue2
   1         A    X         3              xx
   2         B    T         2              xx
PrimaryKey(idEmployee);
ForeginKey(idDataType) References Data(idDataType);
```

**Data** table:

```
idDataType|Description
   1         etc
   2         etc
   3         etc
   4         etc
PrimaryKey(idDataType);
```

Comment: Good question.  You can test this for yourself.  Enter both queries into one SSMS window.  Pressing Ctrl+L will show you the two execution plans.  In this example I suspect both would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not matter, the result will be the same.
Even if they would have different execution times, the DataBase would take care of that so it will always be executed in the fastest possible way.

The `*` has probably a greater impact.